# what is setAPIRootUrl in the JTwitter for android?

Tags: android, twitter

in twitter-compatible API what is setAPIRootURL value ?

```
 twitter=new Twitter("username","password");
 twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
```

[JTwitter library home page](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just points to the api endpoint of your twitter compatible service.

Actual queries then go "below that" like http://yamba.marakana.com/api/timeline/home.json etc.
This Marakana is a public Twitter-like service based on status.net.
Others are identi.ca  (api endpoint is http://identi.ca/api/ ) and so on.

As Daniel wrote, Twitter is the default. The javadoc for setAPIRootUrl says:

```
/**
 * Set this to access sites other than Twitter that support the Twitter API.
 * E.g. WordPress or Identi.ca. Note that not all methods may work! Also,
 * search uses a separate url and is not affected by this method (it will
 * continue to point to Twitter).
 * 
 * @param url
 *            Format: "http://domain-name", e.g. "http://twitter.com" by
 *            default.
 */
public void setAPIRootUrl(String url) {
```

So basically to connect to Twitter you don't need to care about that method.

Comment: sorry I don't understand ,, what i have to set a parameter for setAPIRootUrl()

Comment: There is no one size fits all answer. Where do you want to connect to with your application?

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to Twitter, you can ignore this method.

To expand on Heiko's answer: There are other services like Twitter, which have decided to support the Twitter API. These include identi.ca and Wordpress. The setAPIRootUrl() method allows you to connect to these services. The endpoint will be different for each one. E.g. Heiko listed the identi.ca endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `jtwitter.jar` file into libs folder. Make sure your build path reflects the new location.